# Can't add private framework to project.it says framework not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, frameworks

I added a private framework to my project using link binary with libraries, but when i try to use its methods it say framework not found.The framework is [BluetoothManager](https://github.com/mattlawer/iOS5-Private-Frameworks/tree/master/BluetoothManager) and sometimes it can't recognize bluetooth manager.

EDIT: I have searched the internet and stack overflow and didnt find any correct way to add the private framework to my library.Somebody please guide me step by step to adding a private framework to xcode.

Comment: sometimes? Did you add the framework to your project?

Comment: Yes,I did add the framework to my project.I selected it using the link binary with libraries in build phases of project.am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout if you have missed something from following three steps.

```
1   go to your project targets - search - HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS add your
path

2  select Building phases in settings - choose target dependencies
and add library

3  select Building phases in settings - link binary libraries and
add library.a
```

Enjoy Programming!

Comment: I dont understand your answer foram.there is no such thing as header_search_paths.nor is there any building phases in my xcode. and in 3 did you mean link binary with libraries or link binary libraries?

Comment: go to your project targets

Answer (score 1):

make sure the path to that framework is in the `Framework search path` check `Project info`.

and set that the `framework` should be copied into the destination.